# GitHub Actions how to keep artifacts secret

Tags: github, npm, build, github-actions, vite

I have a little vite project for a single page application on GitHub.
The vite app consumes a REST API.
Due to the nature of vite all environment variables are compiled into the output during `npm run build`.

I want a build process like this:

1. Build stage: inject API URL from github secrets in .env file after that `npm run build`
2. Deploy: deploy to my production server

In my understanding I have to upload the artifact from step 1 and download it in step 2, but this means that everyone that can see the artifacts can see the URL of the production server. I think it is possible to delete the artifact after downloading it from step 1, but there are two problems here:

1. The artifact exists for a short time and the URL can be leaked
2. The artifact maybe exists for a longer time if step 2 fails before deleting

Does anyone know how to achieve this workflow without leaking the production URL?

Maybe I did not find the correct GitHub Actions documentation page.

Comment: I reduced the workflow to one step now, so that I do not have to pass the artifact to the next stage. I can hide my secrets now, but I am still interested in a potential answer, because I would like to have my workflow in two steps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the extremely late response, as you might have already figured this out, but here’s a solution anyway :)

GitHub’s Cache action can also save files, but it does so without uploading it as an artifact, which I think we were both looking for. So here’s an example workflow I put together:

```yaml
jobs:
  save-files:
    name: Save files 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      current_date: ${{ steps.get_date.outputs.CURRENT_DATE }}
    steps:   
      - name: Get date
        id: get_date
        run: |
          echo "CURRENT_DATE=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Save source
        uses: actions/cache/save@v3
        with:
          path: ./generated
          key: dist-files-${{ steps.get_date.outputs.CURRENT_DATE }}

   build:
      name: Load files
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      needs: [save-files]

      steps:
        - name: Restore cached source
          uses: actions/cache/restore@v3
          with:
            path: ./generated
            key: dist-files-${{ needs.save-files.outputs.current_date }}
```

The workflow fails if the cache already exists, which is why I used the timestamp of saving to give each workflow run a unique cache name. I hope this helps!